# Filestream gives an error with spaces

Tags: c#, path, filestream

I am trying to read a file (which works perfectly), the only problem is that when there is a space in the path, the code crashes and tells me there is no such path. Does anyone know how to escape these spaces or another solution? Thanks!

Here is the code I have:

```
public static string ReadValue(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream propertiesFile = new FileStream(ServerLocation + FileName, FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(propertiesFile);
                string Line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (Line != null)
                {
                    if (Line.Contains(value))
                    {
                        var setting = Line.Split('=')[1];
                        Console.WriteLine(setting);
                        sr.Close();
                        return setting;
                    }
                    Line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot find the specified file.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: First of all, you could change "while (Line != null)" with "while "((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)"... now let's see the problem.

Comment: This code is missing calls to Dispose method. You should really consider using the `using` statement.

Comment: Is it really because there's a space? Or is it because there's a missing backslash at the end of ServerLocation?

Comment: Does `ServerLocation` end with a `\`?  You might want to use `Path.Combine(...)` instead.

Comment: Also, it does matter is `ServerLocation` is a UNC vs. local path.

Comment: @jonnyGold It's a local path which will change depending on the location of the file.

Comment: @SteveB Thanks, I've added the using method :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, a path with whitespaces should not pose problems `"C:\My Directory\Files"` should be absolytely ok... maybe you are forgetting slashes somewhere in the begin of ServerLocation or at the end of FileName.

```
String path = Path.Combine(ServerLocation, FileName);
```

Or:

```
FileStream propertiesFile = new FileStream(ServerLocation.Trim() + FileName.Trim(), FileMode.Open);
```

Also, as suggested in my comment, change your loop to:

```
while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (Line.Contains(value))
    {
        var setting = Line.Split('=')[1];
        Console.WriteLine(setting);
        sr.Close();
        return setting;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Path.Combine` seems to fix it atm :).